# OpenText Content Server Search API: Retrieve a file's category data via URL link in XMLformat?

Tags: metadata, opentext, livelink

I've been looking long and hard at documentation and have been googling non-stop but I am falling short.

I am using the OpenText Content Server Search API.

**My goal:** I would like to be able to fetch a file via URL, e.g. `livelinkhost.mycompany.com?func=doc.fetch&nodeid=3670464"`

HOWEVER, I would like to be able to grab that individual file's data stored in its Category section and output it as XML using `&outputformat=xml`

The documentation makes it seem like this is not possible and I feel I am perhaps missing something/going about it the wrong way, using the wrong API etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks :).

Comment: If you're writing a server-side application, you may want to have a look at the web service API, which offers other functionality than document content and meta-data download, which you might need later.  However, as long as you go the simple way of GET requests to well-known URLs, probably authorized by the login cookie, it is OK using the XMLExport suggested by chris here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I shall look into the web service API!

Comment: The WS API has grown since the CS10 release and it's documented in the OT KB (login necessary, unfortunately).  Tools like MSVS or Eclipse will import the WSDL and create a nice API proxy layer in your project, that's why it makes coding in C# or Java so convenient.  The WS bring some standardized functionality but also some overhead, which can be justified for bigger projects.

Comment: Also, there is a new REST API available. But the first version was released in December 2013 for CS10 and CS10.5 and it doesn't offer much functionality yet. It can be [inspected](https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=resources%2Fapis%2Fcontent-server-v1) and [discussed](https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=forums) on a public web site. The REST API has become a buzzword today and additional functionality is more likely to be added there than to other APIs :-) I hope I didn't confuse you too much; if I did, don't worry - you use a public API already and you're on a good way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the category/attribute information as XML with the following:

```
?func=ll&objId=3670464&objAction=xmlexport&attributeinfo=true
```

XMLExport supports a few other parameters, but that's the minimum for getting the category information.

Comment: That works perfectly. I must of missed this in the documentation (albeit I've only been able to have limited access to it!). Thank you so much. The mystery is solved, ha ha.

Comment: A lot of development on this platform requires looking at source and reverse engineering.  I'm glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the web service API provided by the OpenText for the Livelink Content Server? It is very simple to do for those kind of things.